# replace string from tibble with part of that string

Tags: r, regex, stringr, tidytext

I have searched a lot of regex answers here, but can't find the solution to this kind of problem.

My dataset is a tibble with wikipedia links:

```
library(tidytext)
library(stringr)
text.raw <- "Berthold Speer was een [[Duitsland (hoofdbetekenis)|Duits]] [[architect]]."
```

I'm trying to clean up my text from the links.
This:

```
str_extract_all(text.raw, "[a-zA-Z\\s]+(?=\\])")
# [1] "Duits"     "architect"
```

Selects the words i need from between the brackets.

This:

```
str_replace_all(text.raw, "\\[\\[.*?\\]\\]", str_extract(text.raw, "[a-zA-Z\\s]+(?=\\])"))
# [1] "Berthold Speer was een Duits Duits."
```

works as expected, but not quite what i need. This:

```
str_replace_all(text.raw, "\\[\\[.*?\\]\\]", str_extract_all(text.raw, "[a-zA-Z\\s]+(?=\\])"))
# Error: `replacement` must be a character vector
```

gives an error where i expected `"Berthold Speer was een Duits architect"`

Currently my code looks something like this:

```
text.clean <- data_frame(text = text.raw) %>%
  mutate(text = str_replace_all(text, "\\[\\[.*?\\]\\]", str_extract_all(text, "[a-zA-Z\\s]+(?=\\])")))
```

I hope someone knows a solution, or can point me to a duplicate question if there exists one. My desired output is `"Berthold Speer was een Duits architect"`.

Comment: What is the string you want to have at the end?

Comment: `architect`. I want the dots in  `[[ ... ]]` or `[[ xxx | ... ]]`

Comment: `text.raw %>% gsub(pattern = '\\[.+\\|', replacement = '') %>%
    gsub(pattern = '\\]|\\[', replacement = '')`

Comment: Try `gsub("\\[{2}(?:[^]|]*\\|)?([^]|]*)]{2}", "\\1", text)`, see http://ideone.com/ffnxA2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use a single gsub operation

```
text <- "Berthold Speer was een [[Duitsland (hoofdbetekenis)|Duits]] [[architect]]."
gsub("\\[{2}(?:[^]|]*\\|)?([^]]*)]{2}", "\\1", text)
```

See the  [online R demo](http://ideone.com/oakaN8).

The pattern will match

- `\\[{2}` - two `[` symbols
- `(?:[^]|]*\\|)?` - an optional sequence matching

  - `[^]|]*` - zero or more chars other than `]` and `|`
  - `\\|` - a pipe symbol
- `([^]]*)` - Group 1: zero or more chars other than `]`
- `]{2}` - two `]` symbols.

Comment: Your regex skills are ridiculous +1

Comment: If there may be single closing brackets inside replace `[^]|]*` with `[^]|]*(?:](?!])[^]|]*)*` and `[^]]*` with `[^]]*(?:](?!])[^]]*)*` and add `perl=TRUE` argument to gsub.

Comment: Just to add that you can still use `stringr` : `str_replace_all(text, "\\[{2}(?:[^]|]*\\|)?([^]]*)]{2}", "\\1")`